# Kurt Gödel Quote: Why does learning what to disregard improve correct thinking?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

What does Gödel mean by this quote?

[image]

What for example should one disregard?

Comment: Are you asking what Godel himself meant? (i.e. what he intended listeners to get from this statement) -- if so then it would limit good answers to those that invoke his own words.

Answer (score 3):

Descartes famous "rules for the direction of the mind" recommends breaking-up a problem into as many parts as are requisite for its solution. Now, it may have been Leibniz who pointed out that this advice has a significant weak spot, in that it gives no indication as to how far we should go in decomposing our problem. Now, Descartes probably omitted trying to give advice as to how much detail to consider because it is difficult to give good advice on this matter. So Godel's quote may be considered as being his attempt - whilst it, too, is open-ended. So it is natural to want to keep the details to a minimum. But it takes some skill to avoid over-simplification. There is an art to not letting the essential details escape your consideration. So even though Godel uses the somewhat unusual phrase of saying what to "disregard" this is really a literary device to make the point stand out. The vital point - and the art - is to keep in everything that is essential, but no more.

Answer (score 1):

That is called the **principle of economy** in science, also called Occam's Razor ([see for an introduction](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/General/occam.html)).

I was taught: "An engineer is someone who knows what they can disregard." Of course, the more elements one throws into a model, the more complicated it becomes, and the more calculations one has to do.

In practice, what you need to consider in your model should not omit any essential facts (hence it needs to be **complete**, something that Gödel was very interested in). But the **dual** of this rule [its mirror image] is that it should not contain too many entities (hence it should be **economical**). In order to be optimal, your model will have to strike a balance, keeping into account many practical factors (such as the measuring equipment you have, the state of mathematics and calculation techniques, the resources available, etc.).

One of the simplest and most striking examples is celestial mechanics. For calculating the trajectory of Earth around the Solar System with fairly good approximation, you can safely ignore the details of geology, paleontology, history, economics, social sciences, etc. The only thing you need to consider is that our planet is a lump of matter -- and when everything is said and done, a "center of mass", i.e. a pinhead. Fortunately, we do not have to take into account such factors as the level of the seas or the evolution of the New York Stock Exchange.

We could say that this principle of economy was very strikingly embedded in Carl Sagan's comment on the picture of Earth taken by Voyager 1 in 1980, called the "**[pale blue dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Blue_Dot)**":

"The Earth is a very small stage in a vast cosmic arena. Think of the rivers of blood spilled by all those generals and emperors so that in glory and in triumph they could become the momentary masters of a fraction of a dot. Think of the endless cruelties visited by the inhabitants of one corner of the dot on scarcely distinguishable inhabitants of some other corner of the dot. How frequent their misunderstandings, how eager they are to kill one another, how fervent their hatreds. Our posturings, our imagined self-importance, the delusion that we have some privileged position in the universe, are challenged by this point of pale light."
— Carl Sagan, speech at Cornell University, October 13, 1994